# Display Task Sequence Completion Message after Reboot with No User Logged On

Tags: powershell, popup, task, sequence, sccm

In an Upgrade TS I am having trouble displaying a TS completion message.  Most of what I have read and tried seems to assume there is a user logged on and/or the machine never rebooted.
The only thing that has worked is using SMSTSPostAction to provide a popup after the TS has run, and when a user logs on.  But I don't want them logging on until they are presented with a completion message.

Comment: Well what have you tried? Where in *your* code are you struggling? What type of upgrade? You can write a script to check if the version (*if it's software being installed*) has finished, and display the message, while having a task sequence run every hour or so.

Comment: Here's one example...

Comment: <path to…>\x86\ServiceUI.exe -process:TSProgressUI.exe %windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy bypass -nologo -file "C:\Windows\TEMP\UPLIFT\Tools\<Nice script that works on its own for popups>.ps1

Comment: From what I'm reading what I have been trying may not be possible.  But a neat idea I am seeing now is to change the Legal Notice/Logon Screen.